# Error handler is working in every situation

Tags: javascript

Handler is working with my code but it shouldn't alert when the the value is not null. I got an alert in either situations. I don't know what went wrong .

```js
var data = {};
var deviceId = ["asdfa23", "asdfa32"]
    data[deviceId] = "asdfasdf";

try {
  if(data[deviceId].value == null) 
    throw "this is null" 
}
catch(err) {
  alert(err)
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error (the if block is not closed)

Comment: what is the content of the alert ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your in your if statements :

```
(data[deviceId].value == null)
```

by :

```
(data[deviceId] == null)
```

You don't have `value` field, it is not an object.

You can do **.some()** method to check a condition over an array.

```
  var data = {};
  var deviceId = "thermoment123";
  data[deviceId] = ["er213", "er243"];
  for(var device in data){
      try{
        var bool = data[deviceId].some(function(elm){
          return elm
          ? true
          : false
        });
        if (!bool){
          var errorSensor = "The sensor "+ deviceId + " has no data"
          throw errorSensor;
        }
    } catch(err){
          alert(err)
      }
  }
```

Comment: I have edited the code, with a working example with the `some()` method

Answer (score 0):

You assign an array to `data[deviceId]`.

The array has two properties `0` and `1` (along with all the inherited properties like `forEach` and `length`).

`value` is not a property of normal arrays and you haven't added one.

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple syntax errors in your code:

```
var data = {};
var deviceId = "thermoment123";
data[deviceId] = ["er213", "er243"];
for (var device in data) {
    try {
        if  (data[deviceId] == null) { //removed the .value
            var errorSensor = "The sensor " + data[deviceId] + " has no data"; //added ';'
            throw errorSensor;
        } //close brackets that start at from if statement
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err); //added ';'
    }
}
```